# Python List Column Move

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'm trying to move the second value in a list to the third value in a list for each nested list.  I tried the below, but it's not working as expected.

**Code**

```
List = [['a','b','c','d'],['a','b','c','d'],['a','b','c','d']]
print(List)
col_out = [List.pop(1) for col in List]
col_in = [List.insert(2,List) for col in col_out]
print(List)
```

**Result**

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [...], [...]]
```

**Desired Result**

```
[['a', 'c', 'b', 'd'], ['a', 'c', 'b', 'd'], ['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']]
```

**UPDATE**

Based upon pynoobs comment, i came up with the following. But i'm still not there.  Why is 'c' printing?

**Code**

```
List = [['a','b','c','d'],['a','b','c','d'],['a','b','c','d']]
col_out = [col.pop(1) for col in List for i in col]
print(col_out)
```

**Result**

```
['b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: in its current form, pop is removing your entire list. Not the value within the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[List.insert(2,List) for col in col_out]
               ^^^^ -- See below.
```

You are inserting an entire list as an element within the same list. Think recursion!

---

Also, please refrain from using state-changing expressions in list comprehension. A list comprehension should **NOT** modify any variables. It is bad manners!

In your case, you'd do:

```
lists = [['a','b','c','d'],['a','b','c','d'],['a','b','c','d']]
for lst in lists:
    lst[1], lst[2] = lst[2], lst[1]
print(lists)
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'c', 'b', 'd'], ['a', 'c', 'b', 'd'], ['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']]
```

Comment: does modifying vars in list comprehension cause a performance impact?  Why would a for loop perform better?

Comment: No, it is not about performance. It is about not misusing what it offers. The part that comes before the `for` token is purely to *transform* or *map* only the current object being iterated over and create & return a new object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
myList = [['a','b','c','d'],['a','b','c','d'],['a','b','c','d']]
myOrder = [0,2,1,3] 
myList = [[sublist[i] for i in myOrder] for sublist in myList]
```

Comment: This is a valid answer. Don't know why it was downvoted. +1